# Principal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

We have an ideal $I$ of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ with the properties that the lower degree of a nonzero polynomial in $I$ is $n$ and that $I$ contains some monic polynomial of degree $n$. is $I$ principal ideal or not?

I can see the monic polynomial help but not sure how to start.

Comment: This doesn't seem to make much sense. Why are there polynomials contained in an ideal that's a subset of Z?

Comment: I believe you mean $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: yes. sorry I worked on fixing it.

Comment: Consider how you might show that an ideal of $\mathbb Z$ is principal, and how that reasoning might also apply here.

Comment: @StellaBiderman you are right now is okay.

Comment: @πr8 so you mean one of those monic will generate the rest. and did its matter which one the monic we will choose?

Comment: @henry Yes - but if you have two distinct monics of the same degree in an ideal (indeed, any subring), then you should be able to find something of lesser degree (which would be a contradiction to one of your assumptions). // just realised this has been described in an answer below

Comment: @πr8 thanks for your comments its.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p \in I$ be monic of degree $n$. Let $q \in I$. Because $p$ is monic, the remainder of $q$ divided by $p$ has degree $< n$. If this remainder is nonzero then it violates the minimality of $n$ so it must be 0 and thus $p | q$. As this argument applies for all $q \in I$, $I = (p)$.